# Android studio Dolphin - how to manage the size of a button?

Tags: android, button, size

I did search for a long moment a solution on this platform, try many of the proposed solution, but I'm still unable to define the width of a button.

I'm building dynamicaly a tablelayout by adding row. each row contain data but also 2 buttons ichi I'd like to define the width.

```
I  have define a drawable to make the button a circle 

`
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#4CAF50"/>

    <size android:width="10dp"/>
    <size android:minWidth="0dp"/>


    <corners android:radius="99999dp"/>

</shape>
```

```
`
```

here is the code for the button :
`

```
    Button butMoins = new Button(Encodage.this);
    butMoins.setText("-");
    butMoins.setWidth(5);
    butMoins.setBackground(ActivityCompat.getDrawable(Encodage.this, R.drawable.custom_button));
    row.addView(butMoins);
```

`

Running this code  I get
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whVFF.png)

Run the code modified by some suggestion, found :

`

```
    Button butMoins = new Button(Encodage.this);
    butMoins.setText("-");
    butMoins.setWidth(5);
    butMoins.setBackground(ActivityCompat.getDrawable(Encodage.this, R.drawable.custom_button));
    butMoins.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(15, 15));
    row.addView(butMoins,new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(5,5));
```

`

Gives ( I kept the + button with the original code ) :

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJfD8.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="Encodage"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/illustration2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CartedeScore"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

        android:ems="10"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/boarder"

        android:text="@string/Carte"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPartie"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#009688"
        android:ems="10"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/CartedeScore" />



    <TableLayout

        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"

        android:ems="10"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/tblCarte"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I red in one article that there is a by default width for the button widget and none of the suggestion solutions seems to help to update this default value.

Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you share your XML code for the TableLayout?

Comment: Please edit your original question and share the full XML layout containing your TableLayout.

Comment: Updated the question as suggested  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Without running your code, I think the issue is here:

```
<corners android:radius="99999dp"/>
```

This really big corner radius of 99999dp is probably causing your buttons to look like they are in the screenshot. If you want full rounded corners, set the corners to **half the width or half the height** of the button.

So if the button width is 10dp and the height is 10dp, set the corner radius to 5dp.

```
<corners android:radius="5dp"/>
```

Comment: I set high and width to 10 and updated radius to 5 , but the size of the button did not change, the corner are less  round .